# Confusion with signal/source being low or high impedance

Tags: impedance, source

Regarding the following excerpt:

```
High impedance source gives you more volts and less current 
Low impedance source gives you lower voltage but more current
```

What is meant by low impedance source and high impedance source here?
By "impedance" is it meant the output impedance? If so how is that relates to the source utilizing more power? How to comprehend this by circuit model? I came to this confusion after reading about piezoelectric amplifying techniques.

Comment: Impedance is unrelated to voltage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't agree with those statements by themselvas they intend to be generically true but they're not. If a sentence was added like:

```
Given two sources providing the same amount of output power, 
one having a low output impedance and the other having a high output impedance
Then:

High impedance source gives you more volts and less current 
Low impedance source gives you lower voltage but more current
```

Here's an example of both:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fAScMv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Here the load and source impedance are the same, that's because I want to extract the **maximum** amount of power from the source. Both sources will deliver 2 Watts each.

Note how the power in my load resistor is 1 Watt in both cases. In the high(er) impedance case, the voltage is 10x higher but the current is 10x lower.

Comment: How can we relate this to piezoelectric amplifying techniques? Some are called low impedance some are high impedance.